# What is the probability that the value of the two coins he selects will be at least enough to pay the 30 cents toll

Tags: probability

> A driver approaches a toll both and randomly selects two coins from his pocket. If the pocket contains 2 quarters, 2 dimes, and 2 nickels, what is the probability that the value of the two coins he selects will be at least enough to pay the 30 cents toll?

Comment: *Hint:* Doesn't he need to select at least one quarter to pay the toll?  What is the probability of that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*More hint than what Mr. Kemp provided*: Probability of selecting at least one quarter is required. See that there are $2$ quarters in $6$ coins.